# Time decrease, positive percetange

Tags: arithmetic

A simple question but I'll ask anyway, I am writing a report about speed improvements on a particular server task. Originally the task took 4 minutes (240 seconds), it now takes just 10 seconds. How can this be represented as a percentage? I think what I'd like it to say is "this shows a X% improvement, you spent your money wisely". I assume this is possible? I came up with either 230% (doesn't seem right) or 958% (also doesn't seem right).

*Quick note: I couldn't find a tag which this falls under (percentage or algebra) so I've stuck it under homework, maybe someone more experienced on here can amend that for me.*

Comment: You are now saving 230 seconds on the task that needed 240 seconds, so how many seconds will you save if task needed 100 seconds?
$(100*230)/240=95.83 \Rightarrow 95.83 \%$ increase in performance

Comment: Alternatively, what percentage of 240 is 10? => (100*10/240)=4.167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{10}{240}\times100=4.1\dot6$$
Now if ten is $4.1\dot6$% then thats a $100 - 4.1\dot6$% improvement.

Comment: Which would appear to be the 95.83 number that Vikram found above. I'm happy to believe that answer, it just doesn't sound right to me. Tell me, if it were a 100% improvement, would that really equal 0?

Comment: 240% improvement

Comment: so given that 10s is only a little above 0, presumably that makes it a 230% improvement?

Comment: @ChrisNicholson, the word "improvement" used does not belong to any math term

Comment: I was wondering if that was what made this difficult. I think from a maths point of view the best answer is probably 96% decrease in time.

Comment: @ChrisNicholson, correct, even better->time reduced by 96%